# Would a drain line being too low cause a problem for the washing machine pump to run dry and damage the machine?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

The drain line is the standard height, and is the height of the original one when the house was built. Is there a regulation stating it has to be a certain height? If so what is it.

Comment: The problem would be if the standpipe is so low that the "bend" in the drain line sits below the water level in the washer, causing it to siphon.  But even if this happened the washer should not siphon dry to where the pump could be damaged.

Comment: @HotLicks, it would never siphon a washer dry since the siphon would stop once the water level in the washer drops to the level of the end of the drain hose.

Comment: @diceless - Yep, the only way you can come close is if the drain hose has an excessively long piece for inserting into the standpipe.

Comment: To the OP:  Yep, take the drain hose out, and hold it up against the "standpipe" at the point where it would normally rest.  Note where the end of the drain hose is, and what level that is relative to the wash tub.  If the end of the drain hose is above the bottom of the wash tub then there could not possibly be a problem.  (Unless one were to foolishly seal the hose into the standpipe, with no way for air to enter.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a warranty issue with the company blaming you for an installation error.

Your best source of information to fight this will be the install manual that came with the washer (if you don't have it, look it up online).  In there they will list min/max height for drain.